# reading file`s lines char by char into char** array

Tags: c, arrays, string

I wrote the next function that tries to read and enter each line from text file into a string array in c :

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{

        char ** lines;
        readFile(argv[1],lines);

}
int readFile(char* filePath,char** lines)
    {  
    char file_char;
    int letter_in_line=0;
    int line=1;
    char* line_string=malloc(1024);
    int j=1;
    int fd=open(filePath,O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
            return 0;
    }

     while (read(fd,&file_char,1) >0)
     {
             if(file_char != '\n' && file_char != '0x0')
             {
                line_string[letter_in_line] = file_char;
                letter_in_line++;                   
             }                    

             else
             {
                if(lines != NULL)
                {
                    lines=(char**)realloc(lines,sizeof(char*)*line);
                }
                else
                {
                    lines=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
                }
                char* line_s_copy=strdup(line_string);
                lines[line-1]=line_s_copy;
                line++;
                letter_in_line=0;
                memset(line_string,0,strlen(line_string));

             }
             j++;
     }
     printf("cell 0 : %s",lines[0]);

     return 1;
```

}

I have 2 questions :

- 1)Whenever the code reaches the print of cell 0, I'm getting
  Segmentation fault (core dumped) error. What is wrong ?
- 2)In case I 
  want to see the changes in the lines array in my main, I should pass 
  &lines to the func and get char*** lines as an argument ? In
  addition, I will need to replace every 'line' keyword with '*line' ? 
  *I know that I can use fopen,fget, etc... I decided to implement it in this way for a reason.

Comment: "Whenever the code reaches the print of cell 0" Which line of code are you referring to here?

Comment: Also read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging the seg fault.

Comment: printf("cell 0 : %s",lines[0]); one line before the last one

Comment: https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Read_a_file_line_by_line#C

Comment: https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Read_a_file_character_by_character/UTF8#C

Comment: The problem is within the code calling the shown functions. Pleae show it by making a [mcve].

Comment: The code that calling this part is just a simple main that sending a char** variable that was initiated. I edited the main post check it out

Comment: @Konrad, I'm trying to use only system calls

Comment: The answer to number 2 is yes.  This is the root of all the problems.  You need a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to characters or a pointer to an array of pointers to strings.  In C arrays and pointers are the same thing -- it takes a bit to get used to.

Comment: @Hogan got it , thanks . Any idea why I'm getting segmentation issues here ?

Comment: you are getting a segmentation issue because you are accessing protected memory because you are not using enough de-references (following of pointers)

Comment: can u point to a specific example / line ? In this example I wont see all the changes in the main.However It shouldnt explain why I'm getting segmentation error before the function ends.

Comment: `lines` is unitialized, so it's `!= NULL` proabbly and you are then passing it to `realloc`. Passing a pointer not obtained with `malloc` to `realloc` is undefined behavior and seg fault happens. You code has many problems - you leak memory, you leak open file descriptor.

Comment: @JeyJ why overcomplicating such simple things?

Comment: Why are you using `read` instead of `fgetc` and `open` instead of `fopen`? Each call to `read` is a `syscall` requiring the kernel to orchestrate an actual read. By using the `stdio` file-stream function you get default read-buffering that can greatly improve efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many issues that make your code core dump. 
Here a version very similar to your code. I hope it will help you to understand this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int read_file(const char *filename, char ***result)
{

     /* open the file */
     const int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
     if (fd < 0) {
      *result = NULL;
      return -1;
     }
     /* read the file characters by characters */
     char *buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024); 
     char c; 
     int column = 0; 
     int line = 0;
     *result = NULL; 

     /* for each characters in the file */
     while (read(fd, &c, 1) > 0) {
      /* check for end of line */
      if (c != '\n' && c != 0 && column < 1024 - 1) 
           buffer[column++] = c;
      else {
           /* string are null terminated in C */
           buffer[column] = 0;
           column = 0; 

           /* alloc memory for this line in result */
           *result = (char **)realloc(*result, sizeof(char *) *
                      (line + 1));

           /* duplicate buffer and store it in result */
           (*result)[line++] = strdup(buffer);
      }
     }
     free(buffer); 
     return line; 
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     if (argc != 2) {
      fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s [filename]", argv[0]);
      return 1; 
     }

     char **lines; 
     int line_count = read_file(argv[1], &lines);
     if (line_count < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "cannot open file %s\n", argv[1]);
      return 1; 
     }

     for(int i=0; i < line_count; i++)
      printf("%s\n", lines[i]);

     return 0; 
}
```

Here an other version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int read_file(const char *filename, char ***result)
{
     /* init result */
     *result = NULL;

     /* open the file */
     FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
     if (file == NULL)
      return -1;

     /* read the file line by line */
     char *buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);
     int line = 0; 
     while (fgets(buffer, 1024, file)) {
      *result = (char **)realloc(*result, sizeof(char *) *
                     (line + 1));
      (*result)[line++] = strdup(buffer); 
     }
     free(buffer);
     return line; 
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     if (argc != 2) {
      fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s [filename]", argv[0]);
      return 1; 
     }

     char **lines; 
     int line_count = read_file(argv[1], &lines);
     if (line_count < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "cannot open file %s\n", argv[1]);
      return 1; 
     }
     for(int i=0; i < line_count; i++)
      printf("%s\n", lines[i]);

     return 0; 
}
```

Comment: A couple of suggestions, (1) always validate the return of `malloc, calloc, realloc` and (2) there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)